# SQL Server- Merge rows into one column and take maximum count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on a query that will collect data from joining multiple tables and display the data.

The data looks like this:

```
Region                  CountryName  ProductID
Latin America/Caribbean BAHAMAS         21
Europe                  AZERBAIJAN      23
Europe                  AZERBAIJAN      24
Latin America/Caribbean BAHAMAS         21
Middle East/Africa      BAHRAIN         43
Europe                  BALI            21
Asia Pacific            BANGLADHESH     25
Asia Pacific            BANGLADHESH     256
Latin America/Caribbean BARBADOS        20      
Europe                  BELARUS         15
Europe                  BELGIUM         24
```

And I want the result set like this

```
Region                  CountryName                         ProductID       RecordCount
Latin America/Caribbean BAHAMAS,BARBADOS                    21,20           2
Europe                  AZERBAIJAN,BALI,BELARUS,BELGIUM     23,15,24        4
Asia Pacific            BANGLADHESH                         25,26           2
Middle East/Africa      BAHRAIN                             43              1
```

I have tried below Query to merge CountryName and ProductID but I want the 4th Column count value which ever is maximum b/w Product&Country columns. (i.e., If CountryName column has 4 Countries and Product column has 2 then my count should be 4 (2nd Row in the above resultset) and If Product column has two Id and country has single country name then my Count should be 2(3rd row in the above resulset) and it should be grouped by Region.

```
SELECT RegionName,
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(COUNTRY AS NVARCHAR(20)) FROM Countries RX WHERE RX.CountryCode = PD.CountryCode FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CountryList,
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(ProductID AS NVARCHAR(5)) FROM Product RP WHERE RP.ProductID = PD.ProductID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS ProductList,
Count(?) AS recCount
FROM Countries CN WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Product PD WITH (NOLOCK)
ON PD.CountryCode=CN.CountryCode 
GROUP BY RegionName
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query using `stuff()`, `len()` functions and inner join.

```
create table #Region (Region  Varchar(50), CountryName Varchar(50),  ProductID int)
insert into #Region values
('Latin America/Caribbean', 'BAHAMAS', 21),
('Europe', 'AZERBAIJAN', 23),
('Europe', 'AZERBAIJAN', 24),
('Latin America/Caribbean', 'BAHAMAS', 21),
('Middle East/Africa', 'BAHRAIN', 43),
('Europe', 'BALI', 21),
('Asia Pacific', 'BANGLADHESH', 25),
('Asia Pacific', 'BANGLADHESH', 256),
('Latin America/Caribbean', 'BARBADOS', 20),    
('Europe', 'BELARUS', 15),
('Europe', 'BELGIUM', 24)
```

Now the actual query is as shown below:

```
Select a.Region, a.CountryName, b.ProductID, 
Case when LEN(b.ProductID) - LEN(REPLACE(b.ProductID, ',',''))+1 
> 
LEN(a.CountryName) - LEN(REPLACE(a.CountryName, ',',''))+1
then 
    LEN(b.ProductID) - LEN(REPLACE(b.ProductID, ',',''))+1
else
    LEN(a.CountryName) - LEN(REPLACE(a.CountryName, ',',''))+1
end as RecordCount
 from(
Select
    g1.Region
    , stuff((
        select distinct ', ' + g.CountryName
        from #Region g        
        where g.Region = g1.Region 
        for xml path('')
    ),1,2,'') as CountryName    
from #Region g1
group by g1.Region
)a inner join
(
Select
    g1.Region
    , stuff((
        select distinct ', ' + Cast(g.ProductID as CHAR(3))
        from #Region g        
        where g.Region = g1.Region 
        for xml path('')
    ),1,2,'') as ProductID    
from #Region g1
group by g1.Region
)b on a.Region = b.Region
```

The output is as shown below.

```
Region                  CountryName                      ProductID     RecordCount
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Asia Pacific              BANGLADHESH                        25 , 256             2
Europe                    AZERBAIJAN, BALI, BELARUS, BELGIUM 15 , 21 , 23 , 24    4
Latin America/Caribbean   BAHAMAS, BARBADOS                  20 , 21              2
Middle East/Africa        BAHRAIN                            43                   1
```

You can find the live demo [**Here**](https://rextester.com/RQZ58775).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Comment: Wow glad to know that